# Is there a way in power query to split out a sheet of tables into a single table?

Tags: powerquery

As you can see with the below image, I have a sheet that I've imported via PQ and I'm looking to split each row into a separate column where there is a date item i.e. row 14 on the attached image should be where the first split takes place. The end goal being that each date field becomes it's own column with the relevant data underneath.

[The redacted section is where my product codes are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu1U7.png)

Comment: Can you show a example of the output (the table) you want to get, please? Its difficult to get your idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to accomplish this. The following solution reshapes the table without using transpose, which makes it more efficient. It also includes the creation of variables (`ntables`, `nrows`, `ncols`) so that it works with any number of rows and columns. Note that the lack of row headers for the dates and days complicates things a bit, adding a few steps to the code.

Here is the sample table used (included in the M code below):

[image: table_sample]

Here is the code needed to reshape any table with a similar structure to the sample table. If you are unfamiliar with methods for reshaping tables that require the use of helper columns, I suggest that you first go through [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-index-column) that solves a simpler case. Apart from adding the custom variables to make this solution dynamic, the tricky part of this solution lies in computing the `Cumulative Integer-Division` column:

```
let 
    // Import table and remove empty rows
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUtJRMjTUNzDXNzIwMgRxjJA5xnBOrA5YbXBpXkpiJZDhmw9lhJSmFoNYUAVQBOIFFOWngEwxMTG2sIDSlhDa0gCuwgiuyQCLGQR4hibIrjVF5pihOz08NSUP4lSgozNKi6BMt6JMgs63hNFGUNoYxfkGcBwbCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t, Column4 = _t]),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    
    // Define variables used to create helper columns needed to reshape table
    ncols = List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Blank Rows"))-1, /* Minus 1 for the column containing row headers */
    #"Filtered Rows Column1 for Table Count" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Blank Rows", each ([Column1] <> "")),
    ntables = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows Column1 for Table Count", {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})[Count]{0},
    nrows_alltables = Table.RowCount(#"Removed Blank Rows"),
    nrows = nrows_alltables/ntables,

    // Unpivot all columns except first column containing row headers
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Blank Rows", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    // Add helper columns needed for creating the column containing the row headers and for pivoting the table
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], ncols), type number),
    #"Inserted Cumulative Integer-Division for Column Numbers" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Cumulative Integer-Division", each [Modulo]+ncols*Number.IntegerDivide([Index], nrows*ncols), Int64.Type),
    #"Integer-Divided Index" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Cumulative Integer-Division for Column Numbers", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, ncols), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Calculated Modulo of Index" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Integer-Divided Index", {{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, nrows), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom Column for Row Names" = Table.AddColumn(#"Calculated Modulo of Index", "Row Name", each if [Column1] = "" then [Index] else if [Column1] <> "" then [Column1] else ""),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom Column for Row Names",{"Attribute", "Index", "Modulo", "Column1"}),

    // Pivot the Cumulative Integer-Division column to reshape table
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Cumulative Integer-Division", type text}}, "en-GB"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Cumulative Integer-Division", type text}}, "en-GB")[#"Cumulative Integer-Division"]), "Cumulative Integer-Division", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

And here is the result loaded in a worksheet:

[image: table_reshaped]