# Using PowerQuery, is there a way to view a sheet of different-sized groups of data as a single table?

Tags: powerquery

I have a sheet of non-table groups and would like to view them as a single table.

- Each group consists of 4 or 5 rows and 2+ columns with 1 or more blank rows/columns between.
- Overall, the groups are organized into rows and columns on the sheet. There shouldn't be more than 3 groups in a row, but some rows may have blank spaces for future groups.
- New groups and group columns are added regularly so existing groups can be relocated on the sheet anytime.
- The group names are a unique combination of letters and a number. Unfortunately, they are not prefixed "Group" or numbered consecutively like in my example. Giving a generic example that conveys all criteria is harder than it looks .
- This is a shared document so I'd like to avoid making structural changes that would affect other users.

I've experimented with some of the transform options, but I'm new to PQ and didn't make much progress.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69174508/20033948) to a similar question is a step in the right direction, but it looks like I'll need additional steps since my starting data isn't quite as consistent.

Thank you for your time.

[Before Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4MWV.png)
[After Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMB9g.png)

Comment: Are the different items assigned range names? If not, go ahead and do so, then provide a sample input showing each range name input view, and desired output

Comment: @horseyride Sadly, there are no named ranges or tables to use as references to the groups. This is a shared document so I'd like to avoid making structural changes that would affect other users.

Comment: From what you write, and the example you posted, it seems your groups can only be defined by the fact that they occupy different **Areas** on a single worksheet, and the **Area** is defined by being separated from other areas by blank cells.  Also, you cannot apply a range name to any of these groups.  That being the case, I'd suggest you develop a VBA solution, where you can readily examine the worksheet for groups that are in a common area using the `Range.CurrentRegion` property.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the advice! I deliberated on using empty cells to define the groups but ran into the issue of sometimes having consecutive blank rows and columns. Perhaps you're right that a VBA solution would be more appropriate for restructuring this particular data format.